# Простейший сервис на спринг

Tags: java, jquery, json, rest

у меня есть документ с кнопками и обработчик событий, как построить сервис на спринге который будет получать от кнопки поле int с ее номером а в ответ возвращать json строку?

```
       <HTML>

<HEAD>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<TITLE>New One</TITLE>
</HEAD>

<h1 align="center">Настройки</H1>

<BODY BGCOLOR="FFFFFF">

<style>
html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

table {
    margin:10px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    padding:20px;
    height: 90%;
    width: 98%;
}
button {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
div{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
}
form {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
input {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

</style>
<table align="center">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1">
                <button  type="button" name="knopka1">Knopka 1</button>
            </form>
        </td>
        <td>
            <form method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="2">
                <button id="elem2" type="button" name="knopka2">Knopka 2</button>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="3">
                <button onclick="" type="button" name="knopka3">Knopka 3</button>
            </form>
        </td>
        <td>
            <form method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="4">
                <button type="button" name="knopka4">Knopka 4</button>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>

<script>

function foo(event) {

    let $elem = $(event.currentTarget);
    let url = 'http:\\localhost:8080\send_data';
    let url = 'https://arbitaspay.com';


    $.post(url, {'text':$elem.text()}, function(json){

    }, 'json');

}

$(function() {
    $('button').on('click', foo);
});

</script>

</BODY>

</HTML>
```

Comment: element.onlick - может принимать только одно значение. Если оно где-то в HTML или JS уже один раз встречалось, то второй клик к этому элементу уже не привязать. Потому и рекомендуют всё писать на addEventListener... Если надо при клике вызвать function foo() { ... } // Это выглядит так: `document.getElementById('например').addEventListener('click', function(){ foo(); });`

Comment: document.getElementById(elem2).addEventListenner('click', function(){
 alert("click");
}); не работает

Comment: elem2 нужно в кавычках, 'elem2' или "elem2" - без разницы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function clicked2(event) {
  console.log('Нажата кнопка с ID: ' + event.target.id)
  
  console.log('Нажата кнопка со значение: ' + event.target.value)

  alert('Посмотрите в консоль')

  console.log('Обратите внимание на аргумент event в функции clicked.')
  console.log('Подробнее читайте здесь https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener')
  console.log('И здесь https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventListener#Пример')
}

const BUTTON = document.getElementById('elem2')
BUTTON.addEventListener('click', clicked2)

// // Или вот так, значения не имеет
// elem2.addEventListener('click', clicked2)
```

```html
<button id="elem2" type="button" name="knopka2" value="2">Knopka 2</button>
```

Comment: спасибо сделал уже обработчик

Comment: Скрытые поля (type=hidden) не нужны. Сразу на кнопку вешается value. Со спрингом не сталкивался, но возможно этот [канал](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC1g3kT0ZcSXt4_ZyJOshKJQ) заинтересует. Смотрел про vuex, по полочкам всё разложилось в запутанном мозгу.

Comment: я его уже изучил)

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понятно что вам нужно, если же вам нужно обработать каждую кнопку в ваших формах. Есть такой вариант

```
clickFunc(formSelector);
function clickFunc (form) {
    $(form).each(function () {

        let sendBtn = $(this).children('button');

        sendBtn.click(function () {

        });

    });
}
```

Или же такой на js

```
clickFunc();
function clickFunc() {
    let formSectionBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.form > button');

    for (let i = 0; i < formSectionBtn.length; i++){
        formSectionBtn[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
           // code
        });
    }
}
```

вариантов много